# JRuby 9.0.5.0 cannot load compiled ruby files

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

Our application is a RoR app, and currently uses JRuby version 1.7.22, and JRE 8_65.  Our app is an on-prem solution, so we use JRuby to host our application on JVM at the target, Windows Server 2012 R2 system.  We compile our ruby code, using

```
jruby -S jrubyc
```

This takes the .rb file and compiles it to a .class file.  In the original .rb, it loads in the class file, like so.

```
load __FILE__.sub(/\.rb$/, ".class")
```

This all works with JRuby 1.7.22

Now, we want to update JRuby to 9.0.5.0, but are experiencing some problems when it comes to deploying our application.  Basically, that line of code above inside of the .rb file is not working anymore, and we get the error when trying to run a rake db:setup

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: C:/appname/app/models/app_attribute.class is not compiled Ruby; use java_import to load normal classes          
C:/appname/app/models/app_attribute.rb:1:in `<top>'
C:/appname/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top>'
C:/appname/db/seeds.rb:9:in `block in (root)'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Great.  So I replace load with java_import

```
 rake aborted!
 ArgumentError: not a valid Java identifier:         C:/appname/app/models/app_attribute.class
 uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:43:in `block in       java_import'
 uri:classloader:/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:34:in `java_import'
 C:/appname/app/models/app_attribute.rb:1:in `<top>'
 C:/appname/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top>'
 C:/appname/db/seeds.rb:9:in `block in (root)'
 Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Still not working, no matter what I try.  I looked at this post: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3018
I tried to pass the parameter

```
jruby -Xaot.loadClasses=true
```

But I get a warning saying that aot.LoadClasses is not recognized.  EVEN THOUGH I see it in the properties when I type

```
jruby -Xproperties
```

I have done A LOT of research on this, and have probably have looked at everything on the internet regarding this.  Any input will be greatly appreciated.  Is there something I missing?  I am not fully adept in Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

might be the same issue as https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3651

which means you'll need to wait for 9.1 or use a snapshot http://ci.jruby.org/

since, the error is slightly different you should look into reproducing with snapshot and if it fails (might be Windows related) a step-by-step reproduction might speed-up getting the issue resolved.

> jruby -Xaot.loadClasses=true

this is not needed with Warbler

> But I get a warning saying that aot.LoadClasses is not recognized. EVEN THOUGH I see it in the properties when I type

hmm, could you reproduce this with an empty script and no `JRUBY_OPTS` ?

> I have done A LOT of research on this, and have probably have looked at everything on the internet regarding this. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

you might want to try looking into the issue next time :) or considering getting some support

> Is there something I missing? I am not fully adept in Java.

you shouldn't be missing anything - its not a Java issue ...